# When should WiFi Stations switch SSIDs? (according to standard)

Tags: wireless-networking

The WiFi I currently use consists of two APs, each with their own SSID. They're quite well separated by a reinforced concrete ceiling, but their beacons are visible everywhere. My laptop's strategy is to cling to one SSID at all costs, even to the point that DNS lookups consistently fail.

I consider filing a bug because of this - does the wifi standard or other relevant literature mandate something in this particular situation? (I'm a linux user and it's probably NetworkManager)

Comment: If you can get an Ethernet wire to the other side (that is normally do-able) use an Ubiquity Access Point (or like) and use the same SSID.  This works for me

Answer (score 2):

Different SSIDs mean completely different networks. If you want smooth roaming between APs, you should have them both publish the exact same SSID and use the exact same security settings, connect them to the exact same Ethernet LAN, but put them on different non-overlapping channels.

The IEEE 802.11 standards leave all the joining/roaming related decisions up to the client implementations:

- Which SSID to join (most implementations let the user choose, or let the user create a ranked list of preferred SSIDs that can be auto-joined without user intervention).
- Which AP to join, if more than one AP in range is publishing the chosen SSID. This includes which band to join, as a simultaneous dual-band AP is really just two APs in the same box as far as the standards are concerned. (Most client implementations just pick the one with the highest signal strength.)
- When to try to leave the current AP and join another within the same SSID. (Many client implementations have a minimum signal strength threshold, like maybe -70dBm, and won't even think about roaming until the threshold is hit. Then the potential APs to roam to must have signal strength better than the current AP by a certain threshold, like maybe 10dB.)
- When to leave an SSID and join a different one. (Most implementations will not leave an SSID as long as they can stay connected and awake. They won't ever try to join a different SSID unless they completely fall off the network, and can't find any of its APs. Then they refer to their user-ranked list of preferred networks and work down the list seeing if they can find any APs in range publishing that SSID.)

There are a couple optional enhancements in the 802.11 standard that allow APs to provide extra information to clients to help clients decide which AP to join. But this is usually only within the scope of the same SSID. These enhancements aren't widely supported by consumer APs, and they don't change the fact that it's still ultimately up to the client to decide, and the standards never specify how a client should decide. It's left up to the implementors as an implementation detail.

Comment: Though no phones that I know let you do this, many laptops let you tune the roaming aggressiveness of the WiFi adapter. It's usually in the adapter's property pages on Windows machines.

Comment: @Spiff: Thanks for your answer! I think the actual answer part is "it's up to the client to decide" Would you mind if I edited the answer so that's on top? the rest I see as recommendation, which is probably helpful for others.  I'm not the admin of that network, so I'm not changing anything there. I used to have a setup of several APs with the same SSID at home, were we found it inferior to different SSID, because with the same SSID stations still clinged to the "wrong" AP and the UIs do not provide switches for manual override.